# Intercept click/touch event without overriding ViewGroup or View methods

Tags: java, android, android-event

Is there any way how can I intercept/decorate view's touch event without extending `View` or wrapping in some `ViewGroup` (which can intercept child events)?

Suppose I have `ExpandableListView` which handles item click events. If I set in adapter `OnClickListener` or `OnTouchListener` on inflated item view returned by adapter, `ExpandableListView` does not perform corresponding action (group expanding) as event was consumed by item's listener.

The reason why I do not want to use `ExpandableListView#setOnItemClickListener` is, that I want to decorate click event in adapter without using `ExpandableListView` dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution for this problem.

Solution: collecting event clones in `OnTouchListener` and then dispatching them to parent view.

```
private final Queue<MotionEntry> consumedEvents = new LinkedList<>();
private final AtomicBoolean isDispatching = new AtomicBoolean(false);
...
    groupView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override 
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            // we don't want to handle re-dispatched event...
            if (isDispatching.get()) {
                return false; 
            }
            // create clone as event might be changed by parent
            MotionEvent clone = MotionEvent.obtain(e);
            MotionEntry entry = new MotionEntry(v, clone);
            consumedEvents.add(entry);

            // consume ACTION_DOWN in order to receive subsequent motion events 
            // like ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_CANCEL/ACTION_UP...
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return true;
            }
            // we do not want to handle canceled motion...
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                consumedEvents.clear();
                return false;
            }
            // at this moment we have intercepted whole motion 
            // = re-dispatch to parent in order to apply default handling...
            if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                dispatchEvents();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
...
```

Dispatch method:

```
private void dispatchEvents() {
    isDispatching.set(true);
    while (!consumedEvents.isEmpty()) {
        MotionEntry entry = consumedEvents.poll();

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) entry.view.getParent();
        if (parent == null || entry.view.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            continue; // skip dispatching to detached/invisible view
        }
        // make position relative to parent...
        entry.event.offsetLocation(entry.view.getLeft(), entry.view.getTop());
        entry.event.setSource(PARENT_DISPATCHER);
        parent.dispatchTouchEvent(entry.event);

        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            clickListener.onClick(entry.view);
        }
    }
    isDispatching.set(false);
}
```

Helper class

```
private class MotionEntry {
    private final View view;
    private final MotionEvent event;

    public MotionEntry(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        this.view = view;
        this.event = event;
    }
}
```

Comment: PARENT_DISPATCHER is not found.